# how to auto click a button several times in my android app

Tags: android

I want make a button click (loop) several times programmatically in an android app e.g 100 to 200 times.

What I have tried:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
String res;
TextView tv;
EditText ed;
String blure;
Button check;
Button b;
Button gen;


class AnonymousClass_1 implements OnClickListener {
    final /* synthetic */ MainActivity this$0;

    AnonymousClass_1(MainActivity r1_MainActivity) {
        super();
        this$0 = r1_MainActivity;
    }


    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.gen:

                this$0.res = this$0.ffd();
                this$0.res = this$0.res   this$0.GenCD(this$0.res);
                this$0.tv.setText(this$0.res);

            case R.id.btn:


                Button  btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
                String encodedHash = Uri.encode("#");
                String code = "123*";
                String ussdCode ="*";
                TextView jj = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.view);
                String act = jj.getText().toString();
                String b = encodedHash;
                Intent CallIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL", Uri.parse("tel:"   ussdCode   code   act   b));
                startActivity(CallIntent);



        }

    }
}

public MainActivity() {
    super();
    res = "";
}


;                     


public String GenCD(String input) {
    int sum1 = 0;
    int count= input.length() - 2;
    while (true) {
        if (count > 0 || count == 0) {
            sum1  = StrToInt(""   input.charAt(count));
            count -= 2;
        } else {
            count = input.length() - 1;
            while (true) {
                if (count > 0 || count == 0) {
                    sum1  = sumof2(StrToInt(""   input.charAt(count)) * 2);
                    count -= 2;
                } else {
                    String r = ""   (sum1 * 9);
                    return ""   r.charAt(r.length() - 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public int StrToInt(String ch) {
    int count = 0;
    String b = "0";
    while (!b.equals(ch)) {
        count  ;
        b = ""   count;
    }
    return count;}





public String ffd() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    blure = ed.getText().toString();
    return blure   rand.nextInt(10)   rand.nextInt(10)   rand.nextInt(10)   rand.nextInt(10)   rand.nextInt(10)   rand.nextInt(10)   rand.nextInt(10)   rand.nextInt(10)   rand.nextInt(10)   rand.nextInt(10)   rand.nextInt(10)   rand.nextInt(10)   rand.nextInt(10)   rand.nextInt(10);


}
```

But it clicks only once. Any type of help is needed, even those you term irrelevant.

Comment: I think your problem is that you are staring a call before performClick() so you aren't in the same activity anymore.

Answer (score 0):

To click button `b` programaticaly use [`View.performClick()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performClick()) -

```
for(int i=0;i<4; i++){
    b.performClick();    
}
```

Comment: Inside the oncreate method after getting the button by id

Comment: that's my main code, sorry I omitted the oncreate part but it still clicks only once@The_ehT